# error ts6053 file '*.ts' not found

Tags: typescript

Estoy intentado compilar todos los archivos `.ts` pero me sale ese error
en mi consola

```
error ts6053 file '*.ts' not found
```

el comando que ejecuto es:

```
tsc -w *.ts
```

pero si especifico mi archivo, por ejemplo `tsc -w demo.ts` normal compila(transpila) el version de mi typescript es `2.0.9`, como puedo compilar todos mi archivos `.ts` automaticamente(con el `-w`lograba eso). Gracias

Answer (score 2):

En las nuevas versiones typescript esta escuchando todos los .ts por defecto

usa `tsc -w`

Answer (score 1):

yo conseguí la siguiente solucion:

1.- Crear un archivo tsconfig.json donde podrás establecer las opciones para el compiler. Abre una terminal, ubicate sobre el directorio raíz de tu proyecto y ejecuta:

$ tsc --init

## message TS6071: Successfully created a tsconfig.json file.

2.- Por último solo queda ejecutar el compiler sobre el directorio

$ tsc -p ./ -w

y con el -w podras ver como se compila automaticamente si has hecho algun cambio en tus archivos.

Answer (score 0):

Crea un `tsconfig.json`, y ejecuta `tsc` sin argumentos, en el directorio en el que estan.

En la página de TypeScript hay info al respecto y varios ejemplos.